# Javascript MVC Url routing Component, routing in both side

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, url-routing, javascriptmvc

i am making my own small jsmvc lib, and now i want a simple routing lib for my small framwork, i am just wiring up open source libs together to make it work according to my needs,

and now i want a simple url routing componet in my framwork, which can map urls like

`"customUrl/:param1"`
 to 
`"module/controller/action/param1/value1"` to path format

and i also want to create Urls from router like `"roter.createUrl(module/controller/action,{params1:value1});"` to make my rules easy to maintain,

can you please suggest me some good libs or source which have similar functionally.

Comment: What's wrong with BackboneJS's router? You tagged your question with it for some reason. As written, your question currently isn't a good fit for SO == http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: why? backbone is base for most of mvcs out there..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok finnally using crossroads js , and passing route as some custom function

```
addRule:function(pattern, path) {
    var self = this;
    this.router.addRoute(pattern, function() {
        var res = self.resolvePathFormat(path);
        self.dispatch(res.module, res.controller, res.action, res.params);
    });
},
```